# Is there an FMX function to set a TImage's transparent color at runtime?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, firemonkey

I have a TImage on a form in FMX (FireMonkey). I want to load a bitmap into the TImage at runtime, where the bitmap should have a transparent background defined by the first pixel's color in the bitmap. This color might be different from bitmap to bitmap.

I know how to do this at design time, by using the MultiResBitmap editor for a TImage. However, I can't find any examples of how to do this at runtime. Do I have to do this manually (get the color of the first pixel in the bitmap, then iterate through all the pixels and set any that match to transparent), or is there a more simple way to do this?

Comment: What pixel format does your bitmap use?

Comment: Do you mean the TPixelFormat value once loaded? For the test bitmap I just loaded, the TImage's bitmap's PixelFormat value is pfA8R8G8B8.

Comment: The image has an alpha channel. Why are you worrying about transparent color?

Comment: At design time, you can set a 'transparent color' in the MultiResBitmap editor. For example, to Fuschia. Yet, if I load a bitmap with a different background color (say, the equivalent of White), then the background is no longer displayed as transparent. What I am asking is if there is a simple FMX function call to set the image to display that new background color as transparent?

Comment: If the image has an alpha channel, then there is no background or transparent color

Comment: Is there a simple way in FMX to achieve the functional equivalent of setting the 'transparent color' in the MultiResBitmap editor, at runtime?

Comment: Do you know about alpha?

Comment: Do you mean that pixels have an alpha value that determines their opacity?

Comment: Yes. In which case I cannot understand your answer

Answer (score 3):

This function will set a certain color in a bitmap to transparent, i.e., to claNull, using the first pixel's color.

```cpp
void SetTransparent (Graphics::TBitmap *oBmp)
{
  TBitmapData bmpData;
  oBmp->Map (TMapAccess::maReadWrite, bmpData);

  TAlphaColor colorToMakeTransparent = bmpData.GetPixel (0, 0);
  TAlphaColor transparentColor = claNull;

  for (int x=0; x<bmpData.Width; x++)
  {
    for (int y=0; y<bmpData.Height; y++)
    {
      TAlphaColor color = bmpData.GetPixel (x, y);
      if (color == colorToMakeTransparent)
        bmpData.SetPixel (x, y, transparentColor);
    }
  }

  oBmp->Unmap (bmpData);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Perfect! Can set the tiles I have to transparent by replacing white.