# Image Transparency Color in FireMonkey (FMX) with Python

Tags: python, image, firemonkey, transparency, alpha-transparency

I know that the `Image` component support transparency in the [FMX library with Python](https://github.com/Embarcadero/DelphiFMX4Python) as long as the image has transparency built into the image, but what if you want to set a certain color to be the transparency color?

As an example. Let's say I have a PNG Image and I want all white (`$FFFFFFFF`) colors to be transparent, is this possible to do? If yes, then how?

In short, I've created a basic app with a PNG Image on it that has white in it. I want all the white in the image to be transparent. Here's a screenshot of my app:

[image: Python GUI App with Image]

The white part around the circle is supposed to be transparent. I want to set that white color as the transparent color.

It seems like it's definitely possible in the FireMonkey (FMX) framework if you're using C++ Builder or Delphi due to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22948442/2908017) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22950194/2908017). Looks like it can also be done in design time using the Delphi or C++ Builder IDE from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22763198/2908017).

If I do this during design time in a Delphi IDE, then it works fine. I can then also check the `.fmx` code for it and I see there's this line: `MultiResBitmap.TransparentColor = 16777215`. Here's the full `.fmx` code and IDE screenshot for that:

[image: Delphi IDE Image]

```
object MyImg: TImage
    MultiResBitmap.Height = 55
    MultiResBitmap.Width = 70
    MultiResBitmap.TransparentColor = 16777215
    MultiResBitmap = <
        item
        Width = 70
        Height = 55
        PNG = {
            89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D4948445200000046000000370806000000B1503C
            E0000000017352474200AECE1CE90000000467414D410000B18F0BFC61050000
            0110494441546843EDD7410E8320104661EDF13C30D76BC16842090FAB8185F5
            7D1B1B8BB3F803E3384FD1B22CEF744D4208EBBDA7293398F31BBBA78553CBA0
            1A8CA6E9B55D553018608F896A19B86380C100830106039C63803B06180C708E
            899C634E30186030C06080730C70C7008301CE319173CC0906030C06180C708E
            01EE186030C060C04F3DA61CF88E9EB9FBFAA4194C59B0543E7BF7F5393C4A47
            45AF185133D7B3BE3D06180C301880C1B41AD355236AE67AD6F7750DFC5602D5
            A35426DC92D6DE7DFDF6F38BCD17789480CD17F8AD04B0C71C15BD6244CD5CCF
            FA365F6030C0600006D36A4C578DA899EB59DFD73570C003F6186030A07A94CA
            33F9EF6A19AC01E47F3C2D94DD770661FE00988EEB436D12D6BA000000004945
            4E44AE426082}
        FileName = 'C:\Development\Farm\Assets\Dam.png'
        end>
    Position.X = 1156.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 1785.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 64.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 50.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
end
```

But how is this done in Python via code during runtime?

Currently, I am loading the Image by going `self.myImg.Bitmap.LoadFromFile()`. Maybe there is a property in Bitmap or a way to set this transparency color?

Here's my full Python code:

```
from delphifmx import *
import os

class frmMain(Form):
    def __init__(self, owner):
        self.Caption = 'My Form with Transparent Image'
        self.Width = 800
        self.Height = 500

        self.myImg = Image(self)
        self.myImg.Parent = self
        self.myImg.Position.X = 100
        self.myImg.Position.Y = 100
        self.myImg.Width = 300
        self.myImg.Height = 300

        path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        self.myImg.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(path + '\Win64\Debug\Assets\Dam.png')

def main():
    Application.Initialize()
    Application.Title = "My Application"
    Application.MainForm = frmMain(Application)
    Application.MainForm.Show()
    Application.Run()
    Application.MainForm.Destroy()

main()
```

I also tried doing it the way it seems like it is done in the `.fmx` code by using the `MultiResBitmap` Bitmap instead of normal `Bitmap`, but that doesn't work either:

```
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
self.myImg.MultiResBitmap.TransparentColor = 16777215
self.myImg.MultiResBitmap[0].Bitmap.LoadFromFile(path + '\Win64\Debug\Assets\Dam.png')
```